# Убрать точку и цифры после неё

Tags: javascript

Результат выдачи по этому коду:

```js
if(rec) {$("#summ").html(summ.tot);} else {$("#summ").html("0");}
```

например "123456.78", задача убрать точку и цифры после неё, чтоб в итоге получить "123456", при том количество цифр до точки может быть разным, от 1 до 6. Делаю так:

```js
var summa = summ_tot.split('.')[0].replace(/\D+/g,"");
if(rec) {$("#summ").html(summa);} else {$("#summ").html("0");}
```

и получаю ошибку, почему? Как его заставить работать?

Comment: просто используйте округление числа в меньшую сторону Math.floor(summa)

Comment: "и получаю ошибку" - ??

Comment: @Андрій Панчій, благодарю Math.floor(summ.tot), все норм заработало!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var summ_tot = "123456.78";
var summa = summ_tot.split('.')[0].replace(/\D+/g,"");
console.log(summa);
```

Comment: Две переменные var тоже делал, не работает ((

Comment: @Влад Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код".

Comment: в моих реалиях увы не работает, вот я пытаюсь понять почему, может jquery как то иначе выглядит....

Comment: @Igor: а простой `parseInt` уже не в моде? Или я задачу недопонял?

Comment: @UModeL Работает, конечно. Ответ показывает, что ошибка не здесь. Какая ошибка? Угадаем.

Comment: Я в этом направлении совсем не в моде)) Поэтому и прошу помощи)

Comment: @Влад Вы разведчик? Ошибка - секретная?

Comment: @Igor: да нее... Тут похоже шпиён))

Comment: Честному шпиёну нынче не просто)) Всем спасибо за участие, вопрос решен!